# List of CorDapps

Tags: corda

I am trying to identify which CorDapps are running on a node
this information is displayed in the console and in the log during startup
 `Loaded CorDapps                         : blah-1.1.20, corda-core-2.0.0`
**Is there a programmatic way to get that list? (RPC?)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve a list of flows registered on the node using the `CordaRPCOps.registeredFlows` method.

If you want a list of the CorDapp names, you can write a flow that reads them directory from the node's `cordapps` directory, as follows:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class ReadFilesFlow : FlowLogic<List<String>>() {
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): List<String> {
        val cordappDirectory = File("./cordapps")
        val cordappFiles = cordappDirectory.listFiles()
        return cordappFiles.map { file -> file.name }
    }
}
```

You would then retrieve the list of CorDapps via RPC using:

```
CordaRPCOps.startFlowDynamic(ReadFilesFlow::class.java)
```

Note that this wouldn't work in the case of flow tests with a mock network, as the current directory (`./`) wouldn't refer to the node's base directory.

Comment: Wouldn't that miss corda-core?

Comment: Good point. It would. You'd have to remember that this would return the list of CorDapps except `corda-core`.